# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{-x}\sin(x)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, power-series, laplace-transform

In my assignment of Laplace transforms, I have been given the task to evaluate the integral $$\int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{-x}\sin(x)}{x}dx$$ The case when $t\to \infty$ can be easily tackled. But for any $t>0$, it seems rather absurd and tedious, and not at all related to Laplace transform. Here's what I have done.

$$\begin{aligned}
I=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{-x}\sin(x)}{x}dx&=\int_{0}^{t}\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{r}x^{r}}{r!}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx \\ &=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{r}}{r!}\int_{0}^{t}x^{r-1}\sin(x)dx
\end{aligned}$$

Now, using Integration by Parts, I arrived at the following result.
$$\int_{0}^{t}x^{r-1}\sin(x)dx=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}(-1)^{i}i!{r-1\choose i}t^{r-1-i}\sin\left(t+\frac{\pi}{2}(1+i)\right)$$
$$I=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{r}}{r!}\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}(-1)^{i}i!{r-1\choose i}t^{r-1-i}\sin\left(t+\frac{\pi}{2}(1+i)\right)$$

Is there some way to solve this, and is the above evaluation correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no closed form for $t\neq \infty $ so yes, its absurd, it cannot be simplified at all

Comment: try $L(\int dt g(t)))=G(s)/s$ where $G(s)=L(g(t))$
so you have to invert $G(s)=\frac{\pi/2-\arctan(s+1)}{s}$ in the end :)

Comment: the inversion will have to take care of the branchcut(s) of $arctan$ not easy but also not impossible

Answer (score 4):

$\textbf{Hint}$: The function

$$e^tf(t) = \int_0^t\frac{e^{t-x}\sin x}{x}dx$$

is a convolution. The Laplace transform of a convolution is the product of the Laplace transforms. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for answering. If I take the Laplace transform on both sides, then I get $\mathcal{L}\{e^{t}f(t)\}=\cot^{-1}(s)/(s-1)$, or equivalently, $f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\cot^{-1}(s+1)/s\}$. How would one compute this inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: @ParasKhosla in a course about Laplace transforms I would leave the answer in that form.

Answer (score 2):

While also not a Laplace transform, try using the real and imaginary part of $e^{ix}$ and splitting integrals:

$$\int_0^t \frac{\sin(x)}{xe^x}dx=\int_0^t\frac{\frac i2(e^{-ix}-e^{ix})}{xe^x}dx=\frac i2\left(\int_0^t \frac {e^{-(i+1)x}}xdx-\int_0^t \frac{e^{(i-1)x}}xdx\right)$$

Using the [**Exponential Integral $\text{Ei}(x)$**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ExpIntegralEi):

$$\frac i2\left(\int_0^t \frac {e^{-(i+1)x}}xdx-\int_0^t \frac{e^{(i-1)x}}xdx\right)=\begin{cases}\frac i2(\text{Ei}(-(1+i)t)-\text{Ei}((i-1)t)-\frac{3\pi}4,t>0\\ \frac i2(\text{Ei}(-(1+i)t)-\text{Ei}((i-1)t)+\frac\pi4,t<0\end{cases}$$

where the integration is [**correct**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ddx+i%2F2+%28Ei%28-%28i%2B1%29x%29-Ei%28%28i-1%29x%29%29). The indefinite integral looks like a [sine integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sine+integral) or a [cosine integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cosine+integral) function, but I could not get it into those forms. Also, the cases at the very end are due to $$\lim_{x\to0^\pm} \text{Ei}(-(1+i)x)-\text{Ei}((i-1)x)$$ having different results based on if $x<0$ or $x>0$ respectively. If you really want a series expansion, then just expand $e^x$ into one and integrate for $t>0$ to have positive terms:

$$\int \frac{e^{ax}}x dx=\int \frac 1x+\sum_{n=1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}dx=C+\ln(x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{nn!}$$

Comment: $\int_0^t \frac{e^{-x} \sin (x)}{x} \, dx=-\frac{3 \pi }{4}+\frac{1}{2} i (\text{Ei}((-1-i) t)-\text{Ei}((-1+i) t))$ (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BE%5E%28-x%29+Sin%5Bx%5D%2Fx%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+t%7D%5D).

Comment: @StevenClark Even thought the question mentions $t>0$, you have [this other result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-+Integrate%5BE%5E%28-x%29+Sin%5Bx%5D%2Fx%2C+%7Bx%2Ct%2C0%7D%5D)

Comment: Your alternate evaluation seems to indicate there's an error somewhere in Wolfram alpha (and Mathematica), but numerical evaluation of the two integrals is consistent with the the result I illustrated, so it appears the error is in your alternate evaluation. Another problem with your answer is the result should just be a function of $t$, not $x$ and $t$.

Answer (score 2):

The Laplace transform is defined as

$$F(s)=\mathcal{L}_x\left[f(x)\right](s)=\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\, e^{-s\, x}\,dx\tag{1}$$

---

Your integral

$$\int\limits_0^t \frac{e^{-x}\, \sin(x)}{x}\, dx\tag{2}$$

can be represented as the Laplace transform of

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x} (1-\theta(x-t))\tag{3}$$

evaluated at $s=1$ which leads to

$$F(1)=\int\limits_0^t \frac{e^{-x}\, \sin(x)}{x}\, dx=\mathcal{L}_x\left[\frac{\sin(x)}{x} (1-\theta(x-t))\right](1)=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\, (1-\theta (x-t))\, e^{-x} \, dx$$ $$=t \, _1F_4\left(\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4};-\frac{t^4}{64}\right)+\frac{1}{18} t^2 \left(2 t \, _1F_4\left(\frac{3}{4};\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{4},\frac{7}{4};-\frac{t^4}{64}\right)-9 \, _1F_4\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};-\frac{t^4}{64}\right)\right)\tag{4}$$

where $_1F_4$ is the [HypergeometricPFQ function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/).

---

The more general result is

$$F(s)=\mathcal{L}_x\left[\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\, (1-\theta(x-t))\right](s)=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\, (1-\theta (x-t))\, e^{-s\, x}\,dx$$ $$=-\frac{1}{2} i\, \text{Ei}(-((-i+s)\, t))+\frac{1}{2} i\, \text{Ei}(-((i+s)\, t))+\cot^{-1}(s)-\pi\tag{5}$$

which implies

$$F(1)=\frac{1}{2} i\, \text{Ei}((-1-i)\, t)-\frac{1}{2} i\, \text{Ei}((-1+i)\, t)-\frac{3 \pi }{4}\tag{6}$$

is equivalent to the result illustrated in formula (4) above.

Comment: You probably meant $\frac 32$ instead of $\frac42$ in $(2)$ like [in this test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+e+hypergeometricpfq%28%7B1%2F4%7D%2C%7B1%2F2%2C3%2F4%2C5%2F4%2C5%2F4%7D%2C-e%5E4%2F64%29%2Be%5E2%2F18%282+e+hypergeometricpfq%28%7B3%2F4%7D%2C%7B5%2F4%2C3%2F2%2C7%2F4%2C7%2F4%7D%2C-e%5E4%2F64%29-9+hypergeometricpfq%28%7B1%2F2%7D%2C%7B3%2F4%2C5%2F4%2C3%2F2%2C3%2F2%7D%2C-e%5E4%2F64%29%29-integral_0%5Ee+sin%28x%29%2F%28xe%5Ex%29). Maybe the hypergeometric functions simplify?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Yes, $\frac{4}{2}$ makes no sense as Mathematica would have simplified in to $2$. I'm not sure what happened the first time as I just asked Mathematica to copy the formula as Latex.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha_1(s)=\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{t+1}{(t+1)^2+1}\right)$ and $\alpha_2(s)=\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{1}{(t+1)^2+1}\right)$. Since $\frac{1}{x}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xy}\mathrm{d}y$ for any $x>0$ we can say for any $s>0$ that $$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_0^s \frac{e^{-x}\sin(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x &=& \int_0^s\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\sin(x)e^{-xy}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x \\ &=& \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^se^{-x(y+1)}\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\ &=& -\sin(s)\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(y+1)e^{-(y+1)s}}{(y+1)^2+1}\mathrm{d}y-\cos(s)\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-(y+1)s}}{(y+1)^2+1}\mathrm{d}y+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{(y+1)^2+1} \\ &=& -\sin\left(s\right)\mathcal{L}\left(u_{1}(t)\times\frac{t}{t^{2}+1}\right)-\cos(s)\mathcal{L}\left(u_1(t)\times \frac{1}{t^2+1}\right)+ \frac{\pi}{4} \\ &=&-\frac{\sin\left(s\right)}{e^s}\alpha_1(s)-\frac{\cos(s)}{e^s}\alpha_2(s)+ \frac{\pi}{4}\end{eqnarray*}$$

I feel this is a more useful description of this integral as it's now quite easy to establish the fact that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}\sin(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

You can simply evaluate the problem as suggested by @asgeige
$$\mathcal{L}\left[\int_0^{t} \frac{e^{-x} sinx}{x}\right] dx$$

Let $g(t) = \frac{e^{-t} sint}{t}$
And from the fact that
$$\mathcal{L} \left[\frac{f(t)}{t}\right] = \int_s^{\infty} F(y) dy$$
We can write
$$G(s) = \int_s^{\infty} \frac{dy}{(y+1)^2 +1} dy$$
$$G(s) = \pi/2 - \tan^{-1}(s+1)$$
$$G(s) = cot^{-1}(s+1) $$
And from the property of *Laplace* *transform* of integral
$$\mathcal{L}\left[\int_0^t f(\tau) d\tau \right] = \frac{F(s)}{s}$$

Combining the two results we get
$$\mathcal{L}\left[\int_0^{t} \frac{e^{-x} sinx}{x}\right] dx = \frac{cot^{-1} (s+1)}{s}$$